# How can I run multiple asynchronous functions in parallel using asyncio python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have code that sequentially runs asynchronous functions, which in turn make asynchronous requests. How can I run these functions in parallel?

```
for i in get_functions_list:
    try:
        all_data.append(i)
    except:
        continue
```

Now the functions are executed sequentially and it takes about 50 seconds, I want to reduce that time

Comment: What do these functions do? Are they cpu bound? If so, neither `async` not multithreading will help you. You may want to consider `multiprocessing`.

Comment: functions get data from the api and do some calculations

Comment: So, are the api calls network bound? If, so, then you might be able to convert each function to `async` and create a task for each.

Comment: Please include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `asyncio.gather` method to collect all the `async`  functions and then run them **concurrently**.

Here is the some example code that will achieve this:

```py
import asyncio

async def func1():
    print('func1 started')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('func1 finished')

async def func2():
    print('func2 started')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('func2 finished')
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        func1(),
        func2()
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

The code will return this:

```
func1 started
func2 started
func1 finished
func2 finished
```